# Cross-tab in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, crosstab

I am trying to create a query in Postgres to obtain a result in form of table as follows. The idea is to create a table including the value of the variable whose name is variableN at dateM. Instead of creating a full list with the pairs date-value ordered by sensor name, the output would be in table format.

```
logtime     variable1      variable2        variable3
------------------------------------------------------
date1          value11        value12          value13
date2          value21        value22          value23
```

In this way, I am using the function crosstab, but, for me, this function is the first time to be used and I do not have knowledge about it. I have tried several and different ways, but no one works. I would be very grateful with any help.

```
select * from crosstab(
'SELECT sensorhistdatalog.valuedate as logtime, sensorhistdatalog.value as logvalue, sensor.name FROM public.sensor
INNER JOIN public.sensorhistdatalog
ON sensor.id = sensorhistdatalog.sensor_id
where sensorhistdatalog.valuedate between ''2017-03-06'' and ''2017-03-07''
and sensor.name in (''LHTES_ON','C_VELOCIDAD_V3_MAN','C_VELOCIDAD_V4_MAN','VELOCIDAD_V3','VELOCIDAD_V4','LHTES MODE','TEMP_COMF_W','TEMP_COMF_S',
'TO_EXT','TO_INT','TI_EXT','TI_INT','TEMP_PLATE_1','TEMP_PLATE_2','TEMP_PLATE_3','TEMP_PLATE_4','DUMPER_1','DUMPER_2','REF_V3','REF_V4'')
order by name, valuedate asc')
as (
logtime text,
logvalue text,
name text);
```

The crossed tables are sensorhistdatalog and sensor, where sensorhistdatalog has several columns, but we use sensor_id (that is the foreign key from the id of the table sensor), date and value, mainly. Sensor table is basically the list of sensors with id, name and description.

The error is:

```
ERROR: no existing function crosstab(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown)
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your function call the error represents what postgres think it is getting. You might want to try creating a view or a function to give as the argument instead

Comment: my guess would be that there is something wrong with the in statments and the , are read by the server

Answer (score 0):

1. to avoid problem with quotation use `$something$` for whole query
2. format your query for better readable
3. use aliases for tables
4. AS clause does not describe result of your query, it must describes result of `crosstab`

   SELECT * FROM crosstab(

   ```
       $$SELECT shdl.valuedate as logtime,
                shdl.value as logvalue,
                s.name
           FROM public.sensor as s
     INNER JOIN public.sensorhistdatalog as shdl
                ON s.id = shdl.sensor_id
          WHERE shdl.valuedate between '2017-03-06' and '2017-03-07'
            AND s.name in ('LHTES_ON', 'C_VELOCIDAD_V3_MAN', 'C_VELOCIDAD_V4_MAN', 'VELOCIDAD_V3', 'VELOCIDAD_V4', 'LHTES MODE', 'TEMP_COMF_W', 'TEMP_COMF_S', 'TO_EXT', 'TO_INT', 'TI_EXT', 'TI_INT', 'TEMP_PLATE_1', 'TEMP_PLATE_2', 'TEMP_PLATE_3', 'TEMP_PLATE_4', 'DUMPER_1', 'DUMPER_2', 'REF_V3', 'REF_V4'')
          ORDER BY name, valuedate asc
      $$)
      AS (logtime text, variable1 text, variable2 text, variable3 text);
   ```